# Change the speed of clip based on sound track in Premiere pro

Tags: video, premiere, editing, audio

We are currently creating a virtual choir project and we have the tracks from the people already. I am the video editor, we have a sound designer as well. He is making the rythm of the sound perfect right now and I am affraid it will therefore not correspond with the video.

Is there a way in Premiere Pro to change the video speed based upon the finished music track? The app can make Multi-camera sequence based on the audio, can it do something with the speed as well?

Answer (score 0):

you can change the speed of the video making it slow to or fast in order to fit the timing of the music you are using. [image]

How to change a speed duration of the clip?

1. Right click on the clip
2. Click Speed/Duration
3. Adjust the speed. The higher the percentage the faster the clip. The lower the percentage the slower.

Important Notes:

If you increase the speed the clip will be shortened
If you decrease the speed making it slow it will extend the duration of the clip

[image]